# Django cannot migrate on Galera but MariaDB standalone works

Tags: django, kubernetes, mariadb, galera

I'm using Django together with MariaDB, I now moved my application to K8s and my Django migration don't want to run through, instead the whole migration process fails.
On my local development system I'm using a standalone MariaDB instance where everything is working fine. How can it be that the same process is not working against a Galera-Cluster, here the output of my application is the following while trying to migrate all the tables:

```
python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: App, App_Accounts, App_Storages, admin, auth, contenttypes, database, django_celery_results, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying App_Storages.0001_initial... OK
  Applying App_Accounts.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_prometheus/db/common.py", line 71, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'avatar_path' used in key specification without a key length")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 130, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 447, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 199, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_prometheus/db/common.py", line 71, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'avatar_path' used in key specification without a key length")
```

Why do I get this error only with a Galera-Cluster but not with my local MariaDB instance? And how can I possibly fix this.

This is how the field looks like in my models.py:

```
avatar_path = models.TextField(verbose_name="Avatar Path", blank=True, null=True, editable=True, max_length=1000, unique=True)
```

I would actually expect that my migrations will getting processed the same way as with my local MariaDB deployment, which is obviously not the case.

UPDATE:

After deleting the field avatar_path I'm running into exactly the same problem with other fields. Seems this must be a DB engine related issue.
But I'm always running into this when using models.TextField it seems.

Not sure how much it matters but this is the my.cnf config file the Galera-Cluster runs:

```
[client]
port=3306
socket=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/plugin

[mysqld]
performance_schema = on
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
basedir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb
datadir=/bitnami/mariadb/data
plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/plugin
tmpdir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp
socket=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
pid_file=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysqld.pid
bind_address=0.0.0.0

## Character set
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character_set_server=utf8

## MyISAM
key_buffer_size=16M
myisam_recover_options=FORCE,BACKUP

## Safety
skip_host_cache
skip_name_resolve
max_allowed_packet=256M
max_connect_errors=1000000
#sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE
sysdate_is_now=1

## Binary Logging
log_bin=mysql-bin
expire_logs_days=7
# Disabling for performance per http://severalnines.com/blog/9-tips-going-production-galera-cluster-mysql
sync_binlog=0
# Required for Galera
binlog_format=row

## Caches and Limits
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_limit=4M
query_cache_size=256M
max_connections=3000
thread_handling = pool-of-threads
thread_stack = 256K
thread_cache_size = 4
thread_pool_size = 8
thread_pool_oversubscribe = 3
open_files_limit=65535
table_definition_cache=4096
table_open_cache=4096

## InnoDB
innodb=FORCE
innodb_strict_mode=1
# Mandatory per https://github.com/codership/documentation/issues/25
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
# Per https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/08/04/innodb-double-write/
innodb_doublewrite=1
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_file_per_table=1
# 80% Memory is default reco.
# Need to re-evaluate when DB size grows
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=10
innodb_read_io_threads=8
innodb_write_io_threads=6
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_file_format=Barracuda

## Logging
log_error=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/logs/mysqld.log
slow_query_log_file=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/logs/mysqld.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes=1
slow_query_log=1

## SSL
## Use extraVolumes and extraVolumeMounts to mount /certs filesystem
# ssl_ca=/certs/ca.pem
# ssl_cert=/certs/server-cert.pem
# ssl_key=/certs/server-key.pem

[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_sst_method=mariabackup
wsrep_slave_threads=8
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://
wsrep_cluster_name=galera
wsrep_sst_auth="root:"
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=2G; gcache.page_size=2G;"
# Enabled for performance per https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_io_capacity=80000
# MYISAM REPLICATION SUPPORT #
wsrep_replicate_myisam=ON

[mariadb]
plugin_load_add=auth_pam

## Data-at-Rest Encryption
## Use extraVolumes and extraVolumeMounts to mount /encryption filesystem
# plugin_load_add=file_key_management
# file_key_management_filename=/encryption/keyfile.enc
# file_key_management_filekey=FILE:/encryption/keyfile.key
# file_key_management_encryption_algorithm=AES_CTR
# encrypt_binlog=ON
# encrypt_tmp_files=ON

## InnoDB/XtraDB Encryption
# innodb_encrypt_tables=ON
# innodb_encrypt_temporary_tables=ON
# innodb_encrypt_log=ON
# innodb_encryption_threads=4
# innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age=1

## Aria Encryption
# aria_encrypt_tables=ON
# encrypt_tmp_disk_tables=ON
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `TextField` that translates to `Text`, use `models.CharField(verbose_name="Avatar Path", blank=True, null=True, editable=True, max_length=1000, unique=True)`.

While [MDEV-371 Unique indexes for blobs (and Text)](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-371) was implemented in MariaDB, (and the difference in version between your local and Galera version is likely the reason for the error). There have been a few bugs around it recently so using `CharField` translates to `varchar` which doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I'm also thinking about this all the time but is max_length=1000 really valid? I mean, as far as I know, this is limited to 255 character using CharField. Can you explain this here?

Comment: I'm asking as I have to save very large file path references from my s3 storage, which might exceed 255 chars.

Comment: The 255 limit hasn't applied since about MySQL-5.0. There's always the [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/varchar/) that indicate a 65,532 character limit.

Comment: Don't you have to limit it to 767 characters (not 1000) to fit within 3072 max len for indexing?

Comment: Note an [index length of 3076 bytes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-dynamic-row-format/#index-prefixes-with-the-dynamic-row-format) which in utf8mb4 is [char length 768](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZBSrbTIP)